# How to distribute object in between?

Tags: modeling, add-on

How to distribute objects in between? without addon **(not with array).**

[Video](https://youtu.be/4Djrhj64kS8?t=842)
or similar to Sketchup [video](https://youtu.be/ejC7TMKdR7Q?t=85)

When duplicate and press / the value, the object is divided between 2 objects with the value and distributed, and if press * the value a multiplied and distributed.

Comment: Please don't just share a video that we have to watch or scrub through. Links can expire and render your post as unusable. Present all the information directly into this post, be detailed with screenshots of your issue.

Comment: While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Can you illustrate what you mean in the post, please? It's not clear what 'the value a multiplied and distributed' means.

Answer (score 2):

This GN group will give you `amount` linear tweens from the modified object (left) to another with corresponding topology (right)...

[image]

If the target is identical to the source, that's a stretchable array ..

[image]

..if not, distributed shape keys.

The group assumes meshes with faces.

There are obvious possible elaborations; instances along a curve, automatic generation of the target, indexing better suited to  needs.. that would all depend on exactly what you want.

[image]